# What is the difference between 'come to' and 'come at'?

Tags: word-usage

I heard somebody say "come at me".
Why does he use the preposition 'at' instead of 'to'?
I want to know the difference between 'come to me' and ' come at me'.

Answer (score 5):

Without further context, as an idiom, "come at me" can be used to instigate, provoke, or invite another person to attack or fight. Nowadays, you might hear

> Come at me bro!

This dude wants to fight.

Without further context, "come to me" sounds like you are signaling someone to come or move towards you.

Answer (score 3):

In very abstract terms, the preposition **at** expresses (among other things) movement towards with the intention of *striking or making contact*, whereas **to** expresses movement towards with the intention of *reaching*.

The boxer took a swing at his opponent.

They shot arrows at a bale of hay.

The skunk is ruining our picnic. Toss a stone at it to make it go away.

Toss the ball to me.

They threw a life-line to the struggling swimmer.

He drove his friend to the airport.